# Bootstrapping WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, bootstrapping

I'm looking for an good tutorial or article about bootstrapping in WPF.
I am new to WPF an not familar with bootstrapping.

Thanks
Mahus

Comment: You can start here http://www.grumpydev.com/2009/03/08/wpf-bootstrapping-notifyicon-shutdownmode-and-the-mysterious-vanishing-application/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an article on MSDN which talks about bootstrapping:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921139(v=pandp.20).aspx

Good luck with WPF.